# texturing a race track - applying variations

Tags: textures, blender, uv-mapping, 3d-modeling

I have created a simple race track in Blender using bezier curve, array and curve modifiers. A track is created from simple planes and the basic seamless asphalt texture looks quite good. 
[image]
As you can see a basic texture is repeated for a single segment to better match a track scale. I would like to add to the race track some variations, for example a normal map with cracks and transparent texture with tyre marks. I wonder how to achieve a realistic effect. I have two ideas:

- prepare many different textures and load them randomly for a track
  segment
- prepare a few bigger textures, generate somehow a second texture coordinates channel and apply bigger textures for a group of the
  segments

but maybe there is better way.

Finally I would like to export that race track (for example as wavefront obj file) and load in opengl graphics engine using assimp library.

How such texture variations are achieved in games ?

Comment: In blender, you can have two (or more) image textures and use a [mixRGB to combine](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/44629/935) the two, using the alpha of the second image or a third mask image to choose which is visible. You should be able to program the same kind of overlay for any number of additional variations.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a quick and easy method press 5 to enter orthographic mode, press 7 to enter top down view, and finally press the 'U' key over the 3d View and select Project from View. This will overlay the entire 3d plane into the 0-1 space. You can press 5 again to leave Ortho mode.